# How to deploy a POJO file with timer in Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, timer

I have a POJO file that contains a timer function which executes a function at the specified time set as timer.Now as per my need i have to run this file at the time set in the file as timer , but i have no idea how to run this with apache tomcat ..My POJO file is present in my web application.

Do i need this POJO file or need a servlet ?

Here is the POJO file code..

```
class ReportGenerator extends TimerTask {

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Generating report");
    //TODO generate report
}
}

class MainApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    settimer();
}

public static void settimer() {

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.set(
            Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,
            Calendar.MONDAY);
    date.set(Calendar.HOUR, 11);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 51);
    date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    // Schedule to run every MONDAY.
    timer.schedule(
            new ReportGenerator(),
            date.getTime(),
            1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
}
}
```

Please help me as this a roadblock for me..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need some place to start the timer. My suggestion would be to use the ServletContext listeners to load the timer in contextInitialized() method.

It will execute the timer as mentioned.

Kill the Timer in ServletContext contextDestroy() method listener itself.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank u sir for ur answer. will u please give me a code snippet so that i can complete the task as i dont have idea about ServletContext listeners

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/ Please check this link. Inside conextInitialized method create a Object for your class and call the necessary method. Similarly in contextDestroyed Method close all the resource and make the object eligible for garbage collection. If you couldn't understand this, please let me know.

Comment: Thank u sir for ur support i am not getting all the points as how to use this in my case and my code posted in the question..Will u please guide this with my code present in the post..Will be gratefull ..Please sir

Comment: 1. Create a class which implements ServletContextListener interface.

Comment: I created a java class which implements ServletContextListener interface

Comment: 1. Create a class which implements ServletContextListener interface. 2. have instance variable to hold the timer object. 3. Inside the contextInitialized method create a object for your class and instantiate the method which invokes Timer. 4. Similarly, in contextDestroyed() method kill the timer and make it eligible for garbage collection (stop the timer and close all the related resources, if you have any. assign null to the reference).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40935/discussion-between-bennet-and-adi)